# Rewrite query string parameter of url as directory in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, multilingual

I want a query string parameter `lang` become a part of url path. For example,

```
http://www.domain.com/path1/path2/page.php?lang=language&var2=var
```

would be

```
http://www.domain.com/language/path1/path2/page.php?var2=var
```

How can I do that in `htaccess`? There are different pages and directories and parameters, although all of them have same structure. Rule should be general.

Comment: yes it is. It may be en, fa, es , fr ...

Comment: Then you cannot hide it. How will rule know when to add `fr` and when to add `en`?

Comment: There is url like this:
http://www.icounter24.com/panel.php?lang=en&id=548
I want to users enter this url: http://www.icounter24.com/en/panel.php?id=548

Comment: That is understood but when to `fr` and when to add `en`?